# Outside drain - how to replace this grate?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drainage

I'm planning to redo a back entrance into the REO house I bought.
There is this drain: [see images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYQZZ.jpg) which seems like it had a grate on it initially but was broken out?

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's hard to read - but it says: NDS 12 gray, 13 green, 11 black on the edge.

Does anyone know:
How does one fixe or replaces something like that? would have to jackhammer concrete?

P.S. also - What do those numbers even mean?

EDIT: nvm. grate wasnt glued in. I was able to just pull it out by hand and then it turned out that it's a common thing Home Depot carries:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-4-in-Plastic-Round-Black-Foam-Polyolefin-Grate-11/100377398

All fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what the numbers mean but if you get a measurement of the opening and bring that to a metal fabrication shop they may be able to fabricate a screen for you. This would result in a small raised edge, but would eliminate the need to jackhammer the concrete. I don't know what area you live in but i know that most areas have some place like this by just doing a quick search on the internet

Comment: I was able to pull it out by hand and home Depot carried same thing in stock: http://imgur.com/UpZjhdf

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to repair and install a new grate is to: cut away (with a fine toothed hacksaw blade) the remaining broken grate. Plug the hole with a rag to catch falling pieces. File or sand smooth the rough edges. measure the diameter of the opening (it looks to be 4 inches). purchase an appropriate sized drain grate at your local supply store. Finally here's the replacement part[enter link description here](http://stores.drainageproducts.us/4-snap-in-drains-with-stainless-steel-strainer/%20grate). I discovered NDS stands for National Drainage Solutions. I think the color and number titles are descriptive headings for the size and shape of the drain and/or grate.

Comment: I was able to pull it out by hand and home Depot carried same thing in stock: http://imgur.com/UpZjhdf

Answer (score 0):

We just used a flat head screwdriver and needle nose pliers to pull the old broken plastic one out, and replaced it with one purchased at the local Ace hardware store (with a metal grate this time!) and popped it right in.